# Tridion 8.5 UI Extension: Event not trigered on loading publication schema

Tags: gui-extensions

As part of the upgrade from version 7 to 8.5, we are upgrading our UI extensions. Since version 8.5 (in v8 it was ok), we have an issue with an event not being triggered:

```
var view = $display.getView();
$evt.addEventHandler(view.properties.controls.fieldBuilder, "load", this.getDelegate(this.onFormFieldsLoaded));
```

This event was previously triggered before by schema.load(...) and was executed before the schemaLoaded handler. Here is the code:

```
schema = $models.getItem(requiredMedatataSchema.Id);
item.setMetadataSchema(schema);
$evt.addEventHandler(schema, "load", schemaLoaded);
$evt.addEventHandler(schema, "loadfailed", schemaLoadFailed);
schema.load(true, $const.OpenMode.VIEW, false);
```

Now, in 8.5, the event is not triggered anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that item.setMetadataSchema(schema) was not working. Instead I used the following:

```
var view = $display.getView();
view.setSchemaDropdown(schema, view.properties.controls.MetaSchemaDropdown);
view.properties.controls.MetaSchemaDropdown.fireEvent("change");
```